# SummaryType is not displaying in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a table and I want to get summary of each column. I can create summaryRenderer function. But there isn't summaryType feature in grid options so I can not get sum without summaryType. How can I fix it?

[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0yxf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest version of Architect, I can see the option

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnHkF.jpg)